# Audi A4 '05 strange electrical problem?

Tags: headlight, audi, indicators

Actually, I don't even know if it's a problem or a feature. I've seen that if I forget my indicators on (either left or right) and remove the keys + close the door the headlights and the back lights on the same side with the indicators remain lit.

It's my first Audi and I only have it for a month, so excuse the stupid question. Is this a feature of some kind or a possible electrical problem. I should mention that if I leave I don't leave either of the indicators on, the headlights turn off without any problem.

Seems like an electrical problem. I'm amazed that it actually happens every time, on both sides, so it could be some kind of useless feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's actually standard Audi & VW behaviour, not an electrical problem.

Comment: Cool to know. Is there any reason for it? I don't see a practical reason, but then again I'm not the most experienced driver.

Comment: I can't remember why they did it, but I do remember that they've been doing that at least since the late 80s/early 90s.

Comment: Porsches do that as well.  I'm told it's due to some foreign (to the USA) requirement where cars temporarily parked on the street are required to have just one side lit up.

Comment: in the uk its a legal requirement (although no one bothers) to have parking lights on when you are parked on a road with a speedlimit in excess of 30mph or if the vehicle is in excess of 1500kg.

Comment: I remember it was fairly common in Paris for cars on narrow streets to park with two wheels on the sidewalk.  Drivers there usually parked with their side lights on.

Comment: Common in Germany as well. In the US, we tend to drive with our parking lights on rather than park with our parking lights on. We also park in driveways and drive on parkways.

Comment: Yes it's a "feature" for European usage. I hate it because it can run the battery down. On my '04 A4, if you leave the headlights on they shut off automatically, but the parking lights stay on (both sides). In the daytime, it's difficult to notice that until you return to a dead battery.